# Sensitivity and Specificity calculations

Tags: r, sensitivity-analysis

My confusion matrix is as shown below

```
CF_Matrix <-  structure(c(150L, 17L, 3L, 5L), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
    pred = c("0", "1"), truth = c("0", "1")), .Names = c("pred", 
"truth")), class = c("xtabs", "table"), call = xtabs(formula = ~pred + 
    truth, data = testData_pred))

       truth
pred   0   1
   0 150   3
   1  17   5
```

0 represents a non event and 1 represents an event.

I am calculating Sensitivity as

```
 Sens <- CF_Matrix[1,1]/(CF_Matrix[1,1] + CF_Matrix[2,1])
 Sens <- 150/(150+17)
 0.8982036
```

and Specificity

```
 Spec <- CF_Matrix[2,2]/(CF_Matrix[2,2] + CF_Matrix[1,2])
 Sens <- 5/(5+3)
 0.625
```

I want to know if my logic is accurate and hope I am not switching the Sensitivity and Specificity definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct assuming 0 is the positive prediction. You can technically switch Sensitivity with Specificity by switching which class you define as positive.

A really good summary of all the possible calculations for the confusion matrix can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).